# Retrieve Images from ImagePath

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have saved an image path in database like so:

```
C:\Users\3embed\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HeritageWeb\HeritageWeb\Images\startbutton.png
```

I want to display the image as thumbnail. Right now I'm using this code:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="7%" HeaderText="Icon">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="ProfImage" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Thumbnail","/Images/{0}")%>' runat="server" Width="30px" Height="30px"></asp:Image>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And it's giving me the entire path. I just need startbutton.png. However, I need to store the entire path in the database since I need it somewhere else to.

Comment: The *real* problem comes from the data you're storing in DB. Do not store in your database the fullpath of the images, pointing to where your files are stored physically. What would happen when you deploy your application to production? to another server? The path: `C:\Users\3embed\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HeritageWeb\HeritageWeb\Images` whould mean nothing there. You should store only the filename, or the relative path to the image within your web-app.

Comment: Thanks.. exactly what solved my problem  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit messy, but try replacing the following...

```
<%#Eval("Thumbnail","/Images/{0}")%>
```

With (untested **and updated**)...

<strike><%#Eval(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Container.DataItem["Thumbnail"]),"/Images/{0}")%></strike> 
    <%#string.Format("/Images/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Eval("Thumbnail")))%>

Comment: Hey!! Thanks.. I am getting this  error on making the changes:

'System.Web.UI.IDataItemContainer.DataItem' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: @user1340516 Are you using c#? If so change from `("Thumbnail")` to `["Thumbnail"]` (**Update** Sorry, missed the c# tag in your question)

Comment: yes I am using c#.. this is what the error has changed to now.. 
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
thanks

Comment: Sorry, I generally don't use `Eval` so I'm searching in the dark a bit... try the updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the all the replies.. but now i am getting this error:         
The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.Path.GetFileName(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @user1340516 I would recommend that you have a play with what I've given you so far, but instead of using it in the attribute of the `asp:Image` just simply write it to the page, so you can see what's happening. Break it down into component parts... start with display `Eval("thumbnail")` and make sure it shows what you want, then add the `GetFileName` part, and so on... eventually you will (hopefully) get what you need

Comment: @user1340516 if you manage to work out the correct statement, please let me know what it is

Comment: yes i am trying!! Appreciate the help that you provided. i'l post as sooon as i solv it!! Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I changed the stored procedure and it solved my issue.. Thakns for your help!!!