# ImageButton upper folder issue

Tags: html, asp.net

On my website I use imagebutton to display some images.

In my code,

```
<asp:ImageButton ID ="imgb" Width="125px" Height="125px"  runat ="server" ImageUrl ='<%#Eval("ustkategoriresim")%>' CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("ustkatID") %>' />
```

as you can see I use eval to display the image, but the image is on an upper folder. However If I do it like this ;

```
<asp:ImageButton ID ="imgb" Width="125px" Height="125px"  runat ="server" ImageUrl ='../<%#Eval("ustkategoriresim")%>' CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("ustkatID") %>' />
```

It does not work. When I use chrome's tool to check the html code I see this

`src ="../<%#Eval("ustkategoriresim")%>"` instead of the file path.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176176/retrieve-images-from-imagepath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID ="imgb" runat ="server"
    Width="125px" Height="125px" 
    ImageUrl ='<%# "../" + Eval("ustkategoriresim").ToString() %>'
    CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("ustkatID") %>'
/>
```